# Taking the sum of columns and use a threshold to remove

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T, text="dataset  stock  Google Yahoo GTM Microsoft
dataset1 stock1 1       1     1    0
dataset1 stock2 1       0     0    0
dataset1 stock3 1       1     0    0
dataset2 stock1 0       1     1    1
dataset2 stock2 0       0     1    0
dataset3 stock2 1       1     1    0")
```

I would like to take the sum of row and column like this:

and remove the columns which have column sum equal or lower than one

```
   dataset  stock  Google Yahoo GTM Microsoft sum_row
    dataset1 stock1 1       1     1    0     3
    dataset1 stock2 1       0     0    0     1
    dataset1 stock3 1       1     0    0     2
    dataset2 stock1 0       1     1    1     3
    dataset2 stock2 0       0     1    0     1
    dataset3 stock2 1       1     1    0     3
    sum_col  sum_col 4      4     4    1
```

and remove columns which have sum_col equal or lower to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `addmargins` to create a column/row of 'Sum' for the numeric columns after converting to `matrix`.  Then, remove the column that has `sum` less than 2.

```
d1 <- addmargins(`row.names<-`(as.matrix(df1[-(1:2)]), 1:nrow(df1)))
d1[,d1[nrow(d1),]>1]
 #     Google Yahoo GTM Sum
 #1        1     1   1   3
 #2        1     0   0   1
 #3        1     1   0   2
 #4        0     1   1   3
 #5        0     0   1   1
 #6        1     1   1   3
 #Sum      4     4   4  13
```

---

Or another option is `rowSums/colSums`

```
 sum_row <- rowSums(df1[-(1:2)])
 sum_col <- colSums(df1[-(1:2)])

 df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], as.character)
 dfN <- rbind(df1[1:2], list('sum_col', 'sum_col'))
 dfV <- rbind(df1[-(1:2)], as.list(sum_col))

 res <- cbind(dfN, dfV, sum_row=c(sum_row, sum(sum_col)))
 res[setdiff(names(res), names(which(sum_col<2)))]
```

Comment: It works perfect. But could be possible to have the first 2 columns (dataset and stock) or the script doesn't change the series of data so I can paste them? I used the first option

Comment: @Eracog You can do `cbind(dfN, d1[,d1[nrow(d1),]>1])`

Comment: instead of this d1[,d1[nrow(d1),]>1] I use the initial dataframe which is dfN?

Comment: @Eracog the `dfN` is from the 2nd solution after `rbind`ing the `"sum_col"` strings

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing `rowSums` and `colSums` along with `rbind.fill` from `plyr` package,

```
df1$rowsums <- rowSums(df1[,-(1:2)])
df1 <- rbind.fill(df1, as.data.frame(t(colSums(df1[,-(1:2)]))))
df1
#   dataset  stock Google Yahoo GTM Microsoft rowsums
#1 dataset1 stock1      1     1   1         0       3
#2 dataset1 stock2      1     0   0         0       1
#3 dataset1 stock3      1     1   0         0       2
#4 dataset2 stock1      0     1   1         1       3
#5 dataset2 stock2      0     0   1         0       1
#6 dataset3 stock2      1     1   1         0       3
#7     <NA>   <NA>      4     4   4         1      13
```